# How to test a method, what combines RxJava and Suspend fun?

Tags: android, rx-java, mockk

So I have a simple test, where I try to test the error result, something like this:

```
   @Test
    fun `test`() {
        every { Util.fetchLocation()} returns Single.error(Exception())

        val resultErrors = testableClass.testableFun().test().errors()

        Assert.assertTrue(resultErrors.size == 1)
        Assert.assertTrue(resultErrors.firstOrNull() is Exception)
    }
```

Inside the testableClass calls a method, which I mocked.
The problem is, inside this class, I had to map RxJava Single into suspend fun, and after that the suspend fun to Single<> something like this:

```
    private suspend fun getString(): String{
        return "string"
    }

    private fun getIntAsSingle(): Single<Int> {
        return Single.just(2)
    }

    private suspend fun mapSingleToSuspend(){
        getIntAsSingle().await()
    }

    private suspend fun awesomeMethod(): String{
        return getString() + mapSingleToSuspend().toString()
    }

    private fun mapSuspendToSingle(): Single<String>{
        return rxSingle {
            awesomeMethod()
        }
    }
```

The rxSingle method comes from the kotlinx.coroutines.rx2 library

There is no other way to do this, because I have to use the result of first suspend fun with the result of first Single, and after that the return value has to be Single<>

I think, the problem comes from the RxJava await method, because when I tried to debug the test, the test result triggered sooner than the function had been called what contains the await() method.

Inside the test class I used this in the setUp() method to RxJava, but it didn't help:

```
        RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
```

For testing I use JUnit4 with mockk library.